# Facebook custom like button story

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I've been reading up quite a bit, and I hope someone could explain me how to implement it.

The default story that appears on the FB timeline / news feed is: AKG likes Sushi on Sushi Bar.

1. How can I customize this default to text to, say, AKG gave Sushi at Sushi Bar a fresh rating! (from what I've seen, you need to submit something to FB for approval?)
2. Can I add a custom message like:

   AKG likes Sushi on Sushi Bar.
   Click *here* to find out what it's made of. (*here is a link to an URL*)

**Edit**: I've already got all the like buttons set up and it's working fine.

Thank you very much dear SO community - you've been extremely beneficial to my learning journey through PHP and JavaScript (I've got a graphic designer's brain so I'm finding this quite a struggle...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing are custom Open Graph *objects* and *actions*...

*giving a rating* would be considered an action. *Sushi* would be considered an object. The best way to get started is to just start messing around with creating actions & objects. Go to your app settings, then click the **Open Graph** Section. Then click **Getting Started**. It will walk you through setting up an action/object pair. You can test actions and objects without approval, but when you're ready to unleash your app on the world you will have to submit them to FB for approval.

Also, read this...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/

Comment: Ok, and would you know how to do #2?